# erro: __str__ returned non-string (type DetComponente) /

Tags: django, string, templates

Hail Devs. I have had this erro during template rendering. I have tried several resources looking for the error and have not been able to resolve it. I would like some help as to which way to go. Thanks

```
TypeError at /form_mat/
__str__ returned non-string (type DetComponente)
Request Method: GET
Request URL:    http://127.0.0.1:8000/form_mat/
Django Version: 3.2
Exception Type: TypeError
Exception Value:    
__str__ returned non-string (type DetComponente)
Exception Location: C:\webcq\venv\lib\site-packages\django\forms\models.py, line 1253, in label_from_instance
Python Executable:  C:\webcq\venv\Scripts\python.exe
Python Version: 3.8.6
```

models

```
class DetComponente(models.Model):
    componentes = models.CharField (max_length=50, null=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.componentes


class Componente(models.Model):
    componentes = models.ForeignKey (DetComponente, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    descricao = models.CharField (max_length=50)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.componentes


class EspecComponentes (models.Model):
    componentes = models.ForeignKey (Componente, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    codigo = models.ForeignKey (Codigo, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    espec_material = models.ForeignKey (EspecMaterial, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    diametro1 = models.FloatField (blank=True)
    diametro2 = models.FloatField (blank=True)
    peso = models.FloatField (null=True, blank=True)

    class Meta:
        ordering = ['componentes']

    def __str__(self):
        return str (self.componentes)
```

views

```
def view_mat(request, pk):
    data = {}
    data['db'] = EspecComponentes.objects.get(pk=pk)
    return render(request, 'materiais/view.html', data)
```

Answer (score 0):

The `__str__` method must return `str type` value but `DetComponente` is returning `NoneType`. You can check if `DetComponente.componentes` is None and return default string or empty string in that case.

```
class DetComponente(models.Model):
    componentes = models.CharField (max_length=50, null=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.componentes or ""
```

Comment: I did it that way and the error persists.